# Flowtype: package for both typed and untyped users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, flowtype

I have a shared npm package with some business logic consumed by several js apps. There are es6+flow sources files in src and then built vanilla js files in lib, and the package's main is set to lib/index.js, which exports the things that should be visible.

I spent a few days rewriting the package using flow types, which neatened up some of the code and also helped detect some problems. It works great, type checks, and the tests pass. Babel removes all the flow bits so clients that require the package still get the plain files in js and work fine.

But now I would like to allow clients of this package to (optionally) get the type signatures of the functions and check that their calls are correctly typed. I *could* write a declaration file, but it seems silly since the types are already in the original pre-babel source code. At the same time, I can't just provide that source because some clients may not be using flow or babel. And I'd rather not have people that want the types having to know the exact source file path and have to `require('my-package/src/the-piece-i-want')`

Is there a standard way to write a package with flow so that `require('my-package')` *just works* both for plain node users and also type-checks for babel+flow users? If not, what are other people with this problem doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is! Check out this blog post: http://flowtype.org/blog/2015/12/01/Version-0.19.0.html#declaration-files

When you publish your package, just leave a copy of the original source (uncompiled) right next to the compiled version of the file with an extension of `.js.flow`.

So something like:

```
/package.json
/src/index.js          <-- compiled version
/src/index.js.flow     <-- original version
/src/lib/myLib.js      <-- compiled
/src/lib/myLib.js.flow <-- original
```

When Flow sees a `.js.flow` file with the same name as an adjacent `.js` file, it will use the former to shadow the latter.